# Why can't Gradle resolve some dependencies?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

There are some dependencies I can't figure out how to include in my project. I can find all of them on https://mvnrepository.com, I try to include them in my project, but Gradle doesn't seem to resolve them. What are the possible reasons?

This is more like a generic question, as it happened to me a ton of times. What should I investigate in these situations? I tried different version numbers of the packages (sometimes it works, but I have to use older versions),  I tried refreshing all Gradle projects in IntelliJ, but most of the times without any success. At this point including Gradle dependencies seems like a Russain roulette which sometimes turns out well, sometimes... not so much.

I am using **IntelliJ version**: 2017.3.4 and 
**Gradle version**: 2.4.12

Here is an example (I know about Annotations Processing for Lombok, but this example is merely about not being able to resolve the package):

```
group 'com.gaboratorium'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'com.gaboratorium.ctn.CtnApi'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.25' // Unable to resolve
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20' // Unable to resolve

    compile "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.7.1"
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.9.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: Which error does Gradle report exactly? Your build.gradle looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I get "Unable to resolve [package-name]" error. Here is another package I can't import: [Atmosphere Jersey](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.atmosphere/atmosphere-jersey). I tried different version numbers, none of them is being imported. I even tried to state the repository explicitly, like so:

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = "http://central.maven.org/maven2"
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that HTTP proxying was turned on in IntelliJ which was pointing to a Charles proxy, in which I had to add the Maven Central repository to the SSL Proxy location list (I wonder though how some dependencies could be resolved anyway).